# Load external html within chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to load an external html file in my chrome extension. So when I click on a link in the plugin, the new html should be displayed instead of the default popup.

I tried iFrame but that is just placed below the already existing page, it does however let me execute the scripts (which are on the server, signup for example).

When I use regular href with the address it opens in the other window on right click and lets me execute the scripts, but when I enter signup.html it is indeed displayed within the popup, but then I can't execute any scripts because it uses signup.html within the extension folder.

```
<div>
<a href="https://localhost:3014/signup.html" 
width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">Go to dashboard!</a>
</div>



Refused to execute inline event handler because 
it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either 
the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce 
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

The external html is in the folder of the extension (or on the server, depending on what you call within the href), but all the scripts are on the server, and executed there. Credentials are sent to the server.

What about href/external acces am I missing?

EDIT:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Search plugin",
   "description": "A browser plug-in.",
   "background": {
      "scripts": [
      "js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",
      "js/html5sql.js",
      "js/background.js"]
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [
         "js/ready.min.js",
         "js/moment.js",
         "js/content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": false,
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   "permissions": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*",
      "unlimitedStorage",
      "tabs",
      "storage"
   ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "0.0.8",
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon19.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "web_accessible_resources": [
      "js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
   ],
   "icons": {
      "128": "img/icon128.png",
      "48": "img/icon48.png",
      "16": "img/icon16.png"
   }
}
```

Comment: could you post your `manifest.json` here?

Comment: Oh dear, yes that will be the problem I think.. Since I'm building upon an existing plugin I didn't really understand the manifest.

Comment: This seems to be a fairly complicated extension to try to build on, especially if you're just starting out.  The "inline event handler" that Chrome is complaining about means that somewhere, you're including javascript inline: either an "onclick" or "onload", or a script tag that doesn't have a "src" attribute.  Fixing that would be the best way to get this working.

Comment: Not really building upon, but I want to be able to display all of my web application windows inside the plugin. But the files are on the server and need only to be displayed within this plugin, so that the JS calls work (what is working with href='webaddres', but that is a new Chrome tab instead of inside the plugin).

Signup html has an onclick call to a method which makes a request to provide the server with account credentials.